# Send request by ajax on subdomain

Tags: ajax

i want to send a request through ajax on subdomain

the problem is that code :

```
http_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
http_req.open('POST', url, true);
http_req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http_req.send(parameters);
```

is working only with the main domain xxx.com

and i have some pages on my website on subdomains xyn.xxx.com

and i want to send ajax through these subdomains

how to do this

and in this code

```
http_req.open('POST', url, true);
```

the url should be the same url of the page ?

Comment: what errors are you getting? CORS problems?

Comment: you need to allow `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to accept request for sub-domains

Comment: can you tell me how ?

Comment: i tried this in htaccess ( Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" ) but still the request can't be sent